# gitlab ci fails, can't find remote project

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

for almost a month now, I've been strugling with this issue. I just can't manage to solve it...
My gitlab CI pipeline fails with always the same error saying one of my repo can't be found...

```
 The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/bibliotheques/x2_can_port/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/bibliotheques/x2_can_port' into submodule path '/builds/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration/src/lib/x2_can_port' failed
Failed to clone 'src/lib/x2_can_port'. Retry scheduled
```

all my submodules are added with relative url, they all are on the same gitlab server, they all are private and I own all of these repositories.

The only difference between all of these submodules is that some have a main branch (x2_can_port and x2_logger) whereas all others have a master branch...

When I clone the projet locally, of course, it works perfectly fine.

Here, you can find my gitlab ci file, and also my git submodule file

thank you very much for your help

Regards,

Olivier

```
stages:
  - build
  - style
 
build:
  stage: build
  image: gitlab-registry.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMODULE_DEPTH: 1
  script:
    - pwd
    - whoami
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake326 ..
    - cmake326 --build . -j8
 
style:
    stage: style
    image: gitlab-registry.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration
    artifacts:
      untracked: false
      when: on_failure
      expire_in: '1 yrs'
      paths: 
        - "result_clang_tidy.yaml"
    script:
      - mkdir build
      - cd build
      - cmake326 ..
      - cmake326 --build . -j8
      - cd .. 
      - find src/ -iname "*.[ch]xx" | xargs  clang-tidy -p=build --config-file=_clang-tidy --quiet --export-fixes=result_clang_tidy.yaml
      - if [ -s "result_clang_tidy.yaml" ]; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi
```

```
[submodule "src/lib/serial_port"]
    path = src/lib/serial_port
    url = ../bibliotheques/serial_port
[submodule "src/lib/x2_can_port"]
    path = src/lib/x2_can_port
    url = ../bibliotheques/x2_can_port
[submodule "src/lib/x2_data_reader"]
    path = src/lib/x2_data_reader
    url = ../bibliotheques/x2_data_reader
[submodule "src/lib/x2_logger"]
    path = src/lib/x2_logger
    url = ../bibliotheques/x2_logger
[submodule "src/lib/x2_magic_number_generator"]
    path = src/lib/x2_magic_number_generator
    url = ../bibliotheques/x2_magic_number_generator
[submodule "src/lib/x2_shaper_board_interface"]
    path = src/lib/x2_shaper_board_interface
    url = ../bibliotheques/x2_shaper_board_interface
[submodule "src/lib/x2_timestamp_generator"]
    path = src/lib/x2_timestamp_generator
    url = ../bibliotheques/x2_timestamp_generator
[submodule "src/lib/x2_udp_data_logger"]
    path = src/lib/x2_udp_data_logger
    url = ../x2_udp_data_logger
[submodule "extern/doxygen-awesome-css"]
    path = extern/doxygen-awesome-css
    url = https://github.com/jothepro/doxygen-awesome-css.git
[submodule "src/lib/x2_daq_configuration"]
    path = src/lib/x2_daq_configuration
    url = ../bibliotheques/x2_daq_configuration
[submodule "src/lib/agilent_33250a"]
    path = src/lib/agilent_33250a
    url = ../bibliotheques/agilent_33250a
```

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.11.0 (436955cb)
  on ccosvmse0035@gitlab.in2p3.fr 8de310f4, system ID: s_4e9381db672c
  feature flags: FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD:true
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:04
Using Docker executor with image gitlab-registry.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration ...
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
Pulling docker image gitlab-registry.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration ...
Using docker image sha256:874e7054f18eb8e4498a9d2f3bb740797cb8d31b285130e10052ac081eac38bd for gitlab-registry.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration with digest gitlab-registry.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration@sha256:3c159d96d63a20ea2dadb0b69e473bb6a46b085286cdf3c1d0a9a9cadefe5941 ...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on runner-8de310f4-project-19755-concurrent-0 via ccosvmse0035...
Getting source from Git repository
00:04
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration/.git/
Checking out 50092f1b as detached HEAD (ref is feature_calibration_zc_th)...
Updating/initializing submodules recursively with git depth set to 1...
Synchronizing submodule url for 'extern/doxygen-awesome-css'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/agilent_33250a'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/serial_port'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/x2_can_port'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/x2_daq_configuration'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/x2_data_reader'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/x2_logger'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/x2_magic_number_generator'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/x2_shaper_board_interface'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/x2_timestamp_generator'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'src/lib/x2_udp_data_logger'
Entering 'extern/doxygen-awesome-css'
Entering 'src/lib/agilent_33250a'
Entering 'src/lib/serial_port'
Entering 'src/lib/x2_daq_configuration'
Entering 'src/lib/x2_data_reader'
Entering 'src/lib/x2_magic_number_generator'
Entering 'src/lib/x2_shaper_board_interface'
Entering 'src/lib/x2_timestamp_generator'
Entering 'src/lib/x2_udp_data_logger'
Entering 'extern/doxygen-awesome-css'
HEAD is now at 245c7c9 update license file
Entering 'src/lib/agilent_33250a'
HEAD is now at 1bcc6fc fix: typo dans le cmakelists
Entering 'src/lib/serial_port'
HEAD is now at 2ebbccc refactor: suppression de tous les messages sur stdout
Entering 'src/lib/x2_daq_configuration'
HEAD is now at ae86f04 refatctor: suppression des messages sur stdout
Entering 'src/lib/x2_data_reader'
HEAD is now at 2ef502a refactor: changement de nom fonction charge
Entering 'src/lib/x2_magic_number_generator'
HEAD is now at e0e9da4 ops: structuration sous forme de bibliothèque
Entering 'src/lib/x2_shaper_board_interface'
HEAD is now at ab64bf4 ops: réorganisation sous forme d'une bibliothèque
Entering 'src/lib/x2_timestamp_generator'
HEAD is now at 06b0b34 ops: structuration sous forme d'un bibliothèque
Entering 'src/lib/x2_udp_data_logger'
HEAD is now at 1d33d3c fix: ajout header et template
Cloning into '/builds/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration/src/lib/x2_can_port'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/bibliotheques/x2_can_port/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/bibliotheques/x2_can_port' into submodule path '/builds/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration/src/lib/x2_can_port' failed
Failed to clone 'src/lib/x2_can_port'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/builds/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration/src/lib/x2_logger'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/bibliotheques/x2_logger/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/bibliotheques/x2_logger' into submodule path '/builds/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration/src/lib/x2_logger' failed
Failed to clone 'src/lib/x2_logger'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/builds/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration/src/lib/x2_can_port'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/bibliotheques/x2_can_port/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.in2p3.fr/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/bibliotheques/x2_can_port' into submodule path '/builds/xemis/xemis_2/logiciel/x2_calibration/src/lib/x2_can_port' failed
Failed to clone 'src/lib/x2_can_port' a second time, aborting
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I expect to solve this issue and understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: Does the Gitlab username used in CI have access to these failed repositories?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comment. I'm not sure to understand what you're talking about...

Comment: I didn't notice `gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]` in the repository URLs. It looks like a deploy token. Verify if it's valid for the repositories.

Answer (score 8):

I found in repos that my ci could not clone the following parameter

```
settings -> CI/CD -> allow access to this project with a CI_JOB_TOKEN -> add an existing project to the scope.
```

I added my main project repo url to this setting in all projects that could not be cloned and now it works...
gitlab version is  GitLab 15.10. Maybe a parameter that did no exists in earlier version of gitlab.
Olivier